# Why call basic_string::substr with no arguments?

Tags: c++, stdstring

If `s1` and `s2` are strings, then (as far as I can tell)

```
s1 = s2.substr();
```

means exactly the same as

```
s1 = s2;
```

Why would somebody want to call `substr()` without any arguments?

**Edit: Another way to phrase the same question:**

Why does the standard define `substr` thus:

```
basic_string substr( size_type pos = 0,
                     size_type count = npos ) const;
```

rather than thus:

```
basic_string substr( size_type pos,
                     size_type count = npos ) const;
```

Comment: a very good reason : self-documenting code

Comment: the `substr` function - adding the default values gives important clues about how to use the function just by looking at the signature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is, just for the heck of it.
As you rightly noticed, it has no advantage (and sometimes a speed disadvantage) to just creating a copy.

Speculating why the first argument is defaulted at all, I guess that it was meant as a way to force un-sharing of ancient COW strings (not allowed by current standards). Or someone was over-zealous when adding default arguments. It happens to the best of us.

Comment: +1 "someone was over-zealous when adding default arguments" :-)

Comment: @Deduplicator It _may_ have non-speed benefits (in the event that a defaulted `substr()` call doesn't move but range-constructs a copy, this might trim excess capacity that could have been transferred with a move? (Implementation defined; if so, `substr()` becomes similar to `shrink_to_fit` after copy)

Comment: @sehe: There are other and arguably better ways to avoid move-semantics. Also, `shrink_to_fit` is only ever advisory, never mandatory.

Comment: I know. I was just pointing out potential differences to "just assigning" (you said "has no advantage (and sometimes a speed disadvantage)") and I thought I might look the other direction :)

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, the logic might flow better with `substr()`.

Imagine a case where you have a buffer as a string pointer and a pointer to some string metrics object.

```
if (metrics) {
   substring = buffer->substr(metrics->pos(), metrics->len());
} else {
   substring = buffer->substr();
}
```

reads better than

```
if (metrics) {
   substring = buffer->substr(metrics->pos(), metrics->len());
} else {
   substring = *buffer;
}
```

Comment: = That's certainly in the eye of the beholder. And I don't concurr, as it may be longer but not clearer.